# Iterating through Pandas Column and replacing nan values

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, nan

I'm trying to replace missing values in a column with predicted values I have stored in a list.

This is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

```
    A   B   C
0  7.2 'b' 'woo'
1  nan 'v' 'sal'
2  nan 'o' 'sdd'
3  8.1 'k' 'trili'
```

My list would be something like:

```
list = [3.2, 1.1]
```

And my desired outcome is:

```
    A   B   C
0  7.2 'b' 'woo'
1  3.2 'v' 'sal'
2  1.1 'o' 'sdd'
3  8.1 'k' 'trili'
```

I've tried various different approaches towards this problem, but this code illustrates my general idea:

```
q = 0
for item in df['Age']:
    if str(item) == 'nan':
        item = my_list[q]
        q = q + 1
```

Thank you in advance. This has been driving me nuts for a while now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) in something like:

```
df.loc[pd.isnull(df['A']), 'A'] = mylist
```

---

Example:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
     A  B      C
0  7.2  b    woo
1  NaN  v    sal
2  NaN  o    sdd
3  8.1  k  trili

In [20]: mylist = [3.2, 1.1]

In [21]: df.loc[pd.isnull(df['A']), 'A'] = mylist

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
     A  B      C
0  7.2  b    woo
1  3.2  v    sal
2  1.1  o    sdd
3  8.1  k  trili
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
n = iter([3.2, 1.1])
for i, j in zip(*np.where(df.isnull())):
    df.set_value(i, j, next(n), True)

df

     A  B      C
0  7.2  b    woo
1  3.2  v    sal
2  1.1  o    sdd
3  8.1  k  trili
```